# c++: Use type as key for a map/dictionay?

Tags: c#, c++, templates, types

I have the following members in one of my C# classes:

```
private static Dictionary<Type, List<long>> bindings = new Dictionary<Type, List<long>>();

[...]

/// <summary>
/// Register an Action for a specific event type
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Event type</typeparam>
/// <param name="handler">Action to be executed when a message was recieved</param>
/// <returns>Listener ID</returns>
public static long Register<T>(Action<Event> handler) where T : Event
{
        if(handler == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Provided handler is null");
        listeners.Add(nextListenerId, handler);

        AddBinding<T>(nextListenerId);
        nextListenerId++;
        return nextListenerId-1;
}

[...]

    private static void AddBinding<T>(long id) where T : Event
    {
        List<long> b;
        if (!bindings.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out b))
        {
            b = new List<long>();
            bindings.Add(typeof(T), b);
        }
        b.Add(id);

    }
```

I am new to c++ (kinda) and I'm really not sure, how to translate this into c++ (especially the type stuff).

I tried to use type_info as a key in a map, but that does not seem to work

```
'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>::first' uses undefined class 'type_info'
```

Could you give me a hint?
Thanks.

Comment: What does your C++ code look like?

Comment: Post what you have so far Clearly you have something, or that error wouldn't abound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want an answer to the question in the title (I can't make much sense out of C# code): in C++ you can use `std::type_index` as a key for types: you'd use `typeid(x)` to get the type of the expression `x` as a `std::type_info` object which, however, can't be used easily as a key. You can construct a `std::type_index` for this object, though, which can be used as a key, e.g., in a `std::map<K, V>`.

There is another approach to map types to integers which also works quite well, although in the form written below `T const` and `T` will get different values (this can be augmented by normalizing the type before actually obtaining the integer):

```
inline int next_type_key() {
    static int rc = 0;
    return rc++;
}
template <typename T>
int type_key() {
    static int rc = next_type_key();
    return rc;
}
```

You can use this function using e.g.

```
int int_key  = type_key<int>();
int bool_key = type_key<bool>();
```

Once you got a mapping from type to some indexable value it should be straight forward to create a suitable map.

Comment: Is bool_key really correct? Or copy-paste error?

Comment: @hyde: I claim that copy&pasting code is _bad_ but keep getting caught doing it...! I have fixed the issue - thanks!

Comment: First of all, thanks, unfortunately I dont really understand how this works. Is this in the context of a class ? I'm trying to stick to oop as much as possible. How does this ever return the same id? Where does the actual identification of the type take place?

Comment: @user1071988: The code as is would probably to into some namespace. If it make you feel happier, you can put it as `static` or non-`static` member into a `class` although it isn't more blessed either way (I don't believe in object orientation as a goal; I believe in object orientation being a tool like many others). The magic is in the `static` local variables: these get initialized the first time a function is called. Since each instantiation of these templates with a different type is a different function each one used gets its unique integer.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick reply. I understand now - c++ is really different from C#.